# Is it possible to toggle mute in Windows XP from the keyboard?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, audio, mute

Is there some easy and fast way to toggle mute on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com)**.

It's a program that runs in your system tray and, through scripts that you write, allows you to re-map keystrokes.

Scripts for controlling volume are located here:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm

Answer (score 2):

Go to 
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

Then create a shortcut and put

```
“C:\Path\To\nircmd.exe” mutesysvolume 2
```

into the shortcut path. this will create a shortcut somewhere which by double clicking will mute sound. 
If you want, right click, properties and assign a shortcut key to it.

Double clicking it again will unmute the sound. Theres a whole list of stuff you can do with nircmd, just go to the website link and scoll down:-)

Answer (score 1):

I use a little program from NirSoft called [Volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html). This allows you to make shortcuts with your keyboard and mouse to change the system volume.

[image]

I think you can use just the keyboard if you want to.

The other NirSoft program [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) is perhaps a better option.  Volumouse uses the mouse wheel to raise / lower the volume. Here's how to mute the sound with NirCmd:

```
nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A far as I know you can't on a standard keyboard.  However a lot of keyboards these days have a mute switch that can be used to mute the sound(eg Keyboards with media controls)

All you have to do for the keyboard mute to work is install the driver/software for it.

Answer (score 1):

If your audio is coming to you via Flash in your browser, you can install [Flashmute](http://indev.no/flashmute.aspx). It's free. Flashmute will offer you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> as your keyboard toggle.